# Custom help command cog in discord py v2

Tags: python, discord.py, command

So, in the earlier discord py version, i had a separate cog for help command with the follow command

````py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class HelpCommand(commands.HelpCommand):
    colour = 0x0dd2ff

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Cog loaded - HelpCommand.py")

    def footer(self):
        return f"{self.clean_prefix}{self.invoked_with} [command] for more information"

    def get_command_signature(self, command):
        return f"```{self.clean_prefix}{command.qualified_name} {command.signature}```"

    async def send_cog_help(self, cog):
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"**{cog.qualified_name}** commands", colour=self.colour)
        if cog.description:
            embed.description = cog.description

        filtered = await self.filter_commands(cog.get_commands(),sort=True)
        for command in filtered:
            embed.add_field(name=command.qualified_name, value=command.short_doc or "No description")

        embed.set_footer(text=self.footer())
        await self.get_destination().send(embed=embed)

    async def send_command_help(self, command):
        embed = discord.Embed(title=command.qualified_name, colour=self.colour)
        if command.help:
            embed.description = command.help
        embed.add_field(name="Signature", value=self.get_command_signature(command))
        embed.set_footer(text=self.footer())

        await self.get_destination().send(embed=embed)




    async def send_bot_help(self, mapping):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Bot Commands", colour=self.colour)
        description = self.context.bot.description
        if description:
            embed.description = description

        for cog, commands in mapping.items():
            if not cog:
                continue
            filtered = await self.filter_commands(commands, sort=True)
            if filtered:
                value = "\t".join(f"`{i.name}`"for i in commands)
                embed.add_field(name=cog.qualified_name, value=value)

        embed.set_footer(text=self.footer())
        await self.get_destination().send(embed=embed)


async def setup(bot):
    bot.help_command = HelpCommand()
````

I used to call this cog just like other cogs from main.py using

```py
for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

After updating the library to discord py v2, I changed the cogs calling command to

```py
async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

which worked for all cogs except for the help command cog. Can someone please tell me how to rectify this error

Comment: What's the full traceback of the error?

Comment: @EricJin there are no errors thats the problem

Comment: Try printing something in `__init__` to stderr to make sure it’s actually being loaded. Also check the `bot.commands`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

in `on_ready` to load the cogs